# State not showing updated value in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Although the text gets updated on the page, the console.log still logs out the initial value. Why is this? I know that setting the state is asynchronous but why does it still log out the old value even after waiting 1 second?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const [requestState, setRequestState] = useState("initial");

  useEffect(() => {
    setRequestState("changed");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(requestState);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {requestState}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

useEffect will run when the component renders,To call a function conditionally, specify the list of dependencies.
And the rule of thumb is to always add those dependencies that you are using inside the useEffect()

```
    import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    
    function App() {
    const [requestState, setRequestState] = useState("initial");
    setRequestState("changed");  
    useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(requestState);
    }, 1000);
    }, [requestState]);

      return (
        <div className="App">
          {requestState}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: This still prints "initial".

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` depends on the requestState varible, so pass it inside the empty list like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {some code},[used variables])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect()` hook "captures" state and props when it is executed. That is why it has a stale value. The value is from when the function in `useEffect()` was run.

This is a beautiful article by Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/. It has an explanation about almost the exact same problem as yours. Read it completely to have a great insight into `useEffect()`